# Has Bitcoin Cores encryption wallet security ever been bypassable?

Tags: bitcoin-core, encryption, trezor

Every few years there seems to be an exploit found in Trezor that allows people to bypass the security. I was wondering has there every been the same case for Bitcoin Core wallet encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bitcoin core weaknesses?

Bitcoin core wallet encryption uses AES-256-CBC. So far as I know this is still regarded as a good encryption system although people have identified potential [issues with cipher-block-chaining (CBC)](https://blog.cloudflare.com/padding-oracles-and-the-decline-of-cbc-mode-ciphersuites/)

Other likely weaknesses might include

- Poor implementation in Bitcoin core.
- Poor choice of passwords/passphrases by the end-user.
- Poor protection against snooping of in-memory keys etc by Bitcoin core or the OS.
- etc

I don't recall any major issue being reported so far. There are currently 0 [security advisories](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/security/advisories). A quick scan of previous [common vulnerabilities](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures) for wallet related vulnerabilities doesn't find anything.

A careful study of the [release-notes](https://bitcoin.org/en/version-history) or even change-logs for Bitcoin core might reveal the fixing of an exploitable weakness. A careful web-search might throw something up. I haven't found anything but have not spent any time on this.

### Trezor weaknesses

[Published weaknesses](https://news.bitcoin.com/ledger-reveals-physical-exploits-against-trezor-hardware-wallets/) include

- weak proof of genuineness with respect to cloning etc.
- [side-channel attack](https://blog.trezor.io/details-of-security-updates-for-trezor-one-firmware-1-8-0-and-trezor-model-t-firmware-2-1-0-408e59dc012) by measuring power consumption during PIN entry.
- extracting private key or seed from flash memory ICs

These require physical access to the device.

These don't really translate well into possible attacks against bitcoin core.

---

If you run bitcoin core on a PC say, and an attacker gets physical access to your PC, your security is probably gone.

If I had bitcoin core on a PC and suspected someone malicious had had physical access to it, I'd burn the PC and everything it touched, buy a new PC and recreate the wallet from offline backups, then transfer all remaining funds to yet another new/fresh/clean wallet or wallets.